# Losing style when sending div element to email (C#  asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

So I am sending an email filled with the contents of a div element of the page they were on (receipt page). Within the Receipt page the css styling shows up just fine. However, **when the object is sent to e-mail, the styling seems to just disappear**. It is on a separate page and called form within the header (as per usual). I can sort of understand why this is happening (just sending the html to be rendered and not accessing the css styling) but am not sure how to have it resolved.

So my question is, **how can I send this div element without losing the css styling?**

Here is my code for reference:

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter( );
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter( sw );
    invoice.RenderControl( w ); //invoice is the div id of the element i am sending to email
    string s = sw.GetStringBuilder( ).ToString( );


    MailMessage message = new MailMessage( );
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.To.Add( new MailAddress( Session["eMail"].ToString( ) ) );
    message.To.Add( new MailAddress( "email@email.ca" ) );
    message.Subject = "extra dimensional stack-overflow";
    message.From = new MailAddress( "email@email.ca" );
    message.Body = s;

    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient( "localhost", 8025 );
    System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( "blargh", "blargh" );
    emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
```

Comment: try to use inline style, instead of link your div with a css

Comment: I was pretty sure that inline style would work, but I am really hesitant to do that. I would really like to keep it as a separate file

Comment: I have used inline style when sending emails and it works.

Comment: Most email clients strip the <head></head> tags in HTML emails; hence your style elements would too be striped out. Alternatively you can try referencing the .css within your body.

Comment: @Nudier - Thanks for the suggestion. If all else fails, I will definitely do this!

Comment: aren't you not able to reference external stylesheets via <link> from within the body of an html file?

Comment: Have a look at campaign monitor http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/  The list is pretty complete.  All responses here are correct, you cannot use external files or sources from within email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email HTML readers require a mixture of inline styles and, in some clients, HTML-based style markup (rocking like it's 1999). It sucks, but there's a very good reason to this: by referencing any external resources you'd allow users' behavior to be tracked and would open potential security holes. That's why most email programs won't load external images until the user clicks a button. Email clients are not web browsers and should not be expected to behave the same way.

Sorry, but email HTML just requires everything to be included inside the `<body>` (no `<head>` tag, no scripts, and no external resources.)

By the way if you want your email to show up consistently across all clients including Outlook and Outlook Express, you've gotta use table-based layouts as well. Sucks, but true.

Comment: +1 for explaining this thoroughly.  Tables suck, but they have to be used for email :(

Comment: yeah, thanks for that. great explanation, makes absolute sense. sigh, things always take longer than you expect :(

Answer (score 1):

To send html mails, what i do is:

1. Creates a html templates with inline or inpage styles. I do not prefer out side reference,    but still you need, you have to store your css files to some online locations.
2. Similarly , if your template is image rich, upload all the contents of the html like css, images on a remote server.
3. Using a textreader object readall lines using

   > ```
   > using(TextReader reader =new StreamReader(path_of_html_file))
   >   {   
   >     var stringvalue = reader.ReadAllLines()
   >     stringvalue = stringvalue.Replace("[NAME]", db.Value.SomeValue);
   >   }
   > ```
   >
   > // i am not sure about the method
   >   but there methods for the same. this is just for help.
   >            Search and Replace the text with database driven values. Like i generally      use [NAME], [EMAIL] type string on my raw html and replace
   >   them using the db values. **Or you can also use Regex for search and replace in large html documents.**
4. Send your mail using mail body's html property set to true.

Answer (score -1):

to send email with style sheet as follows
**// define your style sheet in invoice div//**

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter( );
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter( sw );
    invoice.RenderControl( w ); //invoice is the div id of the element i am sending to email
    string s = sw.GetStringBuilder( ).ToString( );
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage( );
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.To.Add( new MailAddress( Session["eMail"].ToString( ) ) );
    message.To.Add( new MailAddress( "email@email.ca" ) );
    message.Subject = "extra dimensional stack-overflow";
    message.From = new MailAddress( "email@email.ca" );
    string a,b;
    a="<html><body>";
    b="</body></html>";
    message.Body = a + s + b;
    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient( "localhost", 8025 );
    System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new      System.Net.NetworkCredential( "blargh", "blargh" );
    emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
```